# Set locale just for Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've set my default application locale to `:fa` but I want **Active Admin to use `:en` as its locale**.

I set `default_locale` to `:fa`:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.default_locale = :fa
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts" 
  end
```

But I don't know where can I change the locale for Active Admin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use before_filter to set default_locale: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Switching-locale

In your filter you can determine the namespace: params[:controller].split("/").first